# Screen Size In Pixels

Tags: android

What is the max x, y size of a Android screen in pixels? Is there a standard set by the OS or does it mostly just depend upon the phone hardware.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are informative paragraphs about the question https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Scroll down a bit to see the table.

Note: though the article states that not all screen sizes are represented on the table, for the current version of Android (Froyo 2.2) maximum supported screen size is 480x854.

Answer (score 3):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```